# Java Multithreading - a basic parallel example of Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I would like to create a simple parallel Sieve of Erastosthenes Java program, that would be at least a bit more effective then a serial version I've posted below.

```
  public void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {
      int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(upperBound);
      boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[upperBound + 1];
      for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                  System.out.print(m + " ");
               int threads=4;
               for (int n=1; n<=threads; n++) {
                  int job;
                  if (n==1) {job = m * m;} else {job = (n-1)*upperBound/threads;}
                  int upToJob = n*upperBound/threads; 
                   for (int k = job;  k <= upToJob; k += m)
                  {
                       isComposite[k] = true;
                  }               
               } 
            }
      }
      for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++)
            if (!isComposite[m])
                  System.out.print(m + " ");
  }
```

I have created a loop for dividing work for 4 threads. Though I don't know how to make actual thread code from it. How to send variables and start  4 threads with part of job for each.

Comment: You may want to look into [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can propose following solution: there are 4 workers thread and 1 master thread. Worker threads get jobs from queue. Job is basically 3 numbers: from, to, step. Master mean while must wait until all threads a done. When they're done it searches for next prime number and create 4 jobs. Synchronization between master and workers can be achieved using [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release%28%29): master tries to acquire 4 permits while every worker releases 1 permit when it's done.

```
public class Sieve {

    // Number of workers. Make it static for simplicity.
    private static final int THREADS = 4;

    // array must be shared between master and workers threads so make it class property.
    private boolean[] isComposite;
    // Create blocking queue with size equal to number of workers.
    private BlockingQueue<Job> jobs = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Job>(THREADS);
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    // Create executor service in order to reuse worker threads. 
    // we can use just new Thread(new Worker()).start(). But using thread pools more effective.
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

    public void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {
        int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(upperBound);
        isComposite = new boolean[upperBound + 1];

        // Start workers.
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            executor.submit(new Worker());
        }
        for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                System.out.print(m + " ");
                for (int n=1; n<= THREADS; n++) {
                    int from;
                    if (n == 1) {
                        from = m * m;
                    } else {
                        from = (n-1)*upperBound/THREADS;
                    }
                    Job job = new Job(from, n*upperBound/threads, m);
                    // Submit job to queue. We don't care which worker gets the job.
                    // Important only that only 1 worker get the job. But BlockingQueue does all synchronization for us.
                    jobs.put(job);
                }
                // Wait until all jobs are done.
                semaphore.acquire(THREADS);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // put null to shutdown workers.
            jobs.put(null);
        }
        for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++) {
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                System.out.print(m + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    private class Job {
        public int from, to, step;

        public Job(int from, int to, int step) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.step = step;
        }
    }

    private Worker implements Runnable {
        while (true) {
            Job job = jobs.take();
            // null means workers must shutdown
            if (job == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = job.from; i <= job.to; i += job.step) {
                isComposite[i] = true;
            }
            // Notify master thread that a job was done.
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I couldn't figure out yet, is how exactly jobs.put() and jobs.take() methods work.

Comment: Read documentation on BlockingQueue. Basically put adds element to queue, take returns first element from queue or blocks until someone put element.

Comment: Multithreading this way using a separate thread for partial prime cull (the same prime with different start points and culling span) with a semaphore to await completion of each set of threads isn't as efficient as culling by page segments for all primes that hit that page, with the foreground task just awaiting the completion of each page, assigning new page jobs to the queue upon each comletelion.